# Which is the best way to convert these?

Tags: c#

Datatable dtProduto; (Filled)

```
int cdProduto = Convert.ToInt16(dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdProduto"]);
int cdReferencia = Convert.ToInt16(dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdReferencia"]);
```

The syntax dtProduto.Rows[i][Column] always returns an object, which one is the best way to convert'em to integers?

Regards, Jorge.

Comment: what is there in that object? an int? string encoding of an int? something else? if it's an int, you can just cast etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently converting them to what would be a "short" -- or a 16-bit integer. I don't think there's anything wrong with the way you're doing it now. Simply substitute `Convert.ToInt32()` if you need a 32-bit Integer instead.

If you aren't sure what may be contained in your data source, you might want to be more careful about directly converting your source record data to concrete values by checking for nulls and/or parsing the result. Something like:

```
int value;
if (dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdProduto"] != null)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdProduto"].ToString(), out value))
    {
        // Log exception, throw exception, do nothing, etc.
    } // else row value is now an integer stored in the value variable
}
```

Substitute `short` for `int` if you do want 16-bit integers.

Comment: The not null check is not needed, both fields in the database are not null. But thx anyway.

Comment: Since it's the compact framework i don't have the TryParse function, i should do it like try { int.Parse(...) } catch (Exception ex) { } right?

Comment: @JLFerrari: You can, but don't catch `Exception`, catch `FormatException` instead. There are other exceptions which can be thrown but as long as your numbers are in-bounds and non-null, `FormatException` will likely be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have currently converted them is probably the *safest* approach, assuming the expected data type is fixed. The Convert class performs a variety of checks to make sure that it can convert properly without unexpected exceptions...and in the cases where it can not convert properly, you get specific documented exceptions that you can directly support.

It should be noted that the additional verification adds overhead, and as such, may not be the most performant approach. If you know for sure that the underlying value in those datatable fields are always a specific type, a direct cast is probably the most performant approach...but it could be riskier, and may result in unexpected exceptions.

Comment: +1. However: the database architect must know which are the column types, right? So there must be no risk.

Comment: I imagine these operations are IO bound, though, so the overhead will probably be invisible.

Comment: @Vlad: Possibly, and hopefully. Depends on the company. I've worked for a variety of tech companies over the years...some have whole teams of DBA's, where as others have no DBA at all, and the databases are organic, ad-hoc blobs that grow amorphously over time. @Merlyn: Depends on the volume. There are times when you need to process millions of records in ways not well suited to being done in the database itself...in which case, every little bit counts. The OP never gave any real specifics...so, just trying to cover the bases.

Comment: @Vlad: One other thing...in all my years as a developer, one thing I've learned that should never be taken for granted is the level of risk. I don't think any endeavor can be considered "risk free". The expected outcomes are always the easiest to handle...its the unexpected outcomes that create risk and future nightmares. They are always present...just unknown. Databases in particular tend to be nasty little beasts that cause some of the most arbitrary bugs, all because someone unknowingly mucked around with a schema, inserted invalid data into a weak schema, etc. **There is always risk.**

Comment: @jrista: IMHO in the case of an unexpected column type the program must crash as soon as possible, instead of trying to compensate for mistake and produce seemingly correct result. Imagine that someone changes the column number representation from int to string containing roman numeral :-) If the program won't crash, the code with mistakes has good chances to be deployed to the customer.

Comment: @Vlad: Well, using Convert should produce an exception when the input is in an invalid format...to my knowledge, it is not quite intelligent enough to know that your string contains roman numeral that could technically be converted to a number...it just knows that the string contains more than just numeric characters, and barfs. I agree, the process should halt and not continue if bad data is encountered...using the Convert class to be "safe" won't prevent that...it'll just ensure that a known, expected, and useful exception gets thrown (i.e. not NullReferenceException).

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on how you want to handle it.  Convert will throw an exception, You could also use short.TryParse which doesn't throw an exception.

Read some info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx

I mostly tend to gravitate towards int.TryParse for the performance reasons.

Comment: sorry,Int16 is a short, so short.TryParse() not int

Comment: They might not be strings, in which case `TryParse` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What does this give you?

```
string type1 = dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdProduto"].GetType().Name
string type2 = dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdReferencia"].GetType().Name
```

The database is probably returning the proper object type, in which case you simply need to cast the object to the proper type. This will tell you what that type is, just cast to it, and go. No need to Convert.ToAnything, that's probably doing more work than you need.

You will probably end up with something like this:

```
int cdProduto = (int)dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdProduto"];
int cdReferencia = (int)dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdReferencia"];
```

or if you want something slightly different in C# than the database gives you, something like this:

```
int cdProduto = (int)(ushort)dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdProduto"];
int cdReferencia = (int)(ushort)dtProduto.Rows[0]["cdReferencia"];
```

(In the above code block, the `(ushort)` is a cast of object to ushort, the `(int)` is a conversion of ushort to int.)